# React native Cmd + click (go to definition) not working when using react native '@' alias

Tags: react-native, import, alias

I'm new to React native and a big fan of the '@' alias api used for imports, my one complaint with it is that I now can't use the extremely useful Cmd + click go to definition functionality in vscode.

is there a way to use @ alias imports and set up vscode to recognise the path of the import so that I can keep using the go to definition click shortcut?

example import using alias:

```
import { stringConverter } from '@utils';
```

Comment: This might be due to VSCode doesn't know about your webpack config, you can try create compileOptions.aliases by making a new file jsconfig.js on your project root
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases

Answer (score 1):

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases

### VSCode intellisense config

Try creating `jsconfig.json` in your project root,
Refer to your alias specified in `webpack.config.js`, write the same in the key `compileOptions.aliases`

Just ensure both configuration is the same and it should work.

For example, you might have...
`<project root>/webpack.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, '/src/path/to/utils/'),
    }
  }
};
```

`<project root>/jsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@utils/*": ["./src/path/to/utils/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying this in react native and able to import with alias by configuring it into bable.config, tried mentioning the same in jsconfig.json as you have described but still cmd+click not working and not able to redirect on an actual class defined in alias any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Thank you